# Configuring webpack to work with TypeScript using Babel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to setup my webpack.config.js file to build TypeScript files, but have come across this issue and I can't recall how to fix it.

[image]

Is there something specific I need to add to my config file in order to resolve this issue?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"],
  },
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        use: "file-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({ cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3100
  },
  stats: "errors-only",
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Comment: have you set the [jsx settings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) in your `tsconfig.json` file correctly? Alternative would be to just directly use `react-create-app` and not to hastle with webpack

Comment: does your file have `.js` or `.jsx` extension? Looks like they aren't going through `babel-loader`

Comment: Yes, I am using a tsconfig.json enabling jsx, but that doesn't appear to be the issue.  Also, my file extensions are .ts and .tsx.

Comment: You need to rename your file to use `tsx` extension.

Comment: Did you solve it? Your first image shows it very clear that your file ended in `.ts`, not `.tsx`.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your entry file in your webpack configuration to `index.tsx`

Answer (score 0):

You should add [`babel-preset-typescript`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript) to your `.babelrc`.

```sh
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-typescript
```

```json
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript"]
}
```